# What is the equivalent of ERC-20 tokens on the Cardano blockchain?

Tags: decentralized-exchange, defi, altcoin

Ethereum, with its first mover advantage, is the basis for hundreds of ERC-20 tokens that rely on the Ethereum blockchain. Right now, virtually all altcoins listed on decentralized exchanges like Uniswap are ERC-20 tokens, making Ethereum a monster in DeFi.

What is the equivalent of ERC-20 tokens for Cardano? Are there any tokens, DApps or independent projects based on the Cardano blockchain. If so, name some top examples.

Why doesn't Uniswap (a decentralized exchange) list anything Cardano-related?

I heard Cardano makes use of an "ERC-20 converter" but not sure what that means for the question

Answer (score 2):

I think this question will be closed as off-topic as it's a question about Cardano. (Please ask on a Cardano forum.)

Just to clear one thing up:

> Why doesn't Uniswap (a decentralized exchange) list anything Cardano-related?

Uniswap is a smart contract on the Ethereum blockchain. It has no knowledge that Cardano exists. (See the first question in their FAQ: https://uniswap.org/faq/)

Comment: do you know of a decentralized exchange in the works that will do for Cardano-based tokens what Uniswap does for Ethereum-based tokens?

Comment: @user610620 You would have a better chance to get an answer from the cardano community